# What is the security of the Firebase Auth REST API?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I know there are several ways to access Firebase Authentication, but if I use the Firebase Auth REST API and the Firebase Authentication Unity SDK, are they both secure? What is the security of the REST API and the Firebase Authentication Unity SDK? Is one more secure than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and simple answer is obviously **yes**, they are both really secure.

Firebase Auth is maintained by Google and used in very large projects. OAuth with SSL is quite secure and I can assure you it's more secure than almost anything you could write on your own.

It's very hard to answer to "it's one more secure that the other", this question is really vague and hard to find a definitive answer. If your client-side is compromised or you do not enforce good enough server-side security rules and checks of course it does not matter how secure their APIs really are.